# Project reference problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

My project has some references. One of them has no path. I can't view it in object browser.  When i want to remove it, my project closed.

I can't remove or change this reference. What can i do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your project file with notepad and check the problem. (.csproj in case of C# project)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has a specific editor for project files, if you can open the solution which contains your project then if the project icon is grayed out just right click on it and select edit, you will have the project file opened in the text editor with xml schema validation and intellisense.